# How to add javascript content in asp.net page

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am trying to add a very simple sage payment wall in my webpage and when I import the script it seems not be calling the js script. I'm new to asp.net and cannot figure out how to execute the script block, im using code behind as well in C#. This is my very simple asp.net code for transaction processing.

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="MG_CreditCard_Authenticator_1.Default" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>


<html>

<head runat="server">
    <title>Default</title>


</head>



<body>

    <form id="form1" runat="server"  >
            <div id="topLevel" runat="server" margin="100px">
                <asp:Label id="InvoiceLable" runat="server" Text="Invoice" />
                <asp:TextBox id="InvoiceTextBox" runat="server" TextMode="Password" />
            </div>

            <div id="secondTopLevel" runat="server" >
                <asp:Label id="DateLabel" runat="server" Text="Date"/>
                <asp:TextBox id="DateTextBox" runat="server"/>
            </div>
            <div id="thirdTopLevel" runat="server">
                <asp:Button id="button1" runat="server" Text="Finish" OnClick="button1Clicked" />
            </div>
            <div id="form2" runat="server">

                <asp:TextBox id="postInflow" runat="server" Height="200px" Width="400px" ReadOnly="true" TextMode="MultiLine" />
                <asp:Button id="genRecipt" runat="server" Text="Generate" OnClick="ACHauth"  />

                <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.sagepayments.net/pay/1.0.2/js/pay.min.js"></script>

    <!--                <script language="javascript"src='<%=ResolveUrl("PaymentHandler.js")%>' type='text/javascript'</script> 
     -->

            </div>          
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

And this my C# code behind code

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;

namespace MG_CreditCard_Authenticator_1
{

    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        String invoiceNumber = "Invoice Number";
        //String Date = "";
        //String outputData = "";
        //int buttonclicks = 0;


        public void button1Clicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {

            button1.Text = "Done";
            invoiceNumber = InvoiceTextBox.Text;
            InvoiceLable.Text = "Invoice Number";
            postInflow.Text = "Displaying info for Invoice Number: "+InvoiceTextBox.Text+" made on "+DateTextBox.Text;

            Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("Registration", ResolveUrl("/Users/ShashankMurthy/Projects/MG_CreditCard_Authenticator_1.03/MG_CreditCard_Authenticator_1.03/PaymentHandler.js"));

        }

        public void GetValue(String key){

            var appConfig = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(key);
        }
        public void ACHauth(object sender, EventArgs args){
        }
      }
    }
```

I have tried all the solutions I could find online, but the javascript function is not being called.

Javascript file I created for the script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    PayJS(['PayJS/UI'], // loading the UI module...
    function($UI) { // ... and assigning it to a variable
        $UI.Initialize({
            elementId: "paymentButton",
            // identifiers (no keys!):
            clientId: "myClientId", // https://developer.sagepayments.com/user/register
            merchantId: "999999999997",
            // auth, covered later:
            authKey: "ABCD==",
            salt: "DEFG==",
            // config:
            requestType: "payment", // or "vault" to tokenize a card for later
            amount: "1.00",
            orderNumber: "Invoice12345",
            // convenience:
            addFakeData: true,
        });
    });
</script>
```

Updated asp.net code

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="MG_CreditCard_Authenticator_1.Default" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>


<html>

<head runat="server">
    <title>Default</title>


</head>



<body>

    <form id="form1" runat="server"  >
            <div id="topLevel" runat="server" margin="100px">
                <asp:Label id="InvoiceLable" runat="server" Text="Invoice" />
                <asp:TextBox id="InvoiceTextBox" runat="server" TextMode="Password" />
            </div>

            <div id="secondTopLevel" runat="server" >
                <asp:Label id="DateLabel" runat="server" Text="Date"/>
                <asp:TextBox id="DateTextBox" runat="server"/>
            </div>
            <div id="thirdTopLevel" runat="server">
                <asp:Button id="button1" runat="server" Text="Finish" OnClick="button1Clicked" />
            </div>
            <div id="form2" runat="server">

                <asp:TextBox id="postInflow" runat="server" Height="200px" Width="400px" ReadOnly="true" TextMode="MultiLine" />

                <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.sagepayments.net/pay/1.0.2/js/pay.min.js"></script>

                               <button id="paymentButton">
                    Click
                </button>

                <script type="text/javascript">
                        PayJS(['PayJS/UI'], // loading the UI module...
                        function($UI) { // ... and assigning it to a variable
                            $UI.Initialize({
                                elementId: "paymentButton",
                                // identifiers (no keys!):
                                clientId: "myClientId", // https://developer.sagepayments.com/user/register
                                merchantId: "999999999997",
                                // auth, covered later:
                                authKey: "ABCD==",
                                salt: "DEFG==",
                                // config:
                                requestType: "payment", // or "vault" to tokenize a card for later
                                amount: "1.00",
                                orderNumber: "Invoice12345",
                                // convenience:
                                addFakeData: true,
                            });
                        });
                </script>




            </div>



    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is no element in the html with the id `paymentButton`.

Comment: I had that and all that happen was a flash of screen. I did see the screen flash, but nothing other than that

Comment: A javascript file should not contain `<script type="text/javascript">`  Are you using a JS debugger in the browser?

Comment: @ZeroDayFracture if you have the script attaching to one of your asp buttons its probably doing a post back to the server and causing the page to refresh.

Comment: @xavier no and should it just be javascript then?

Comment: @ZeroDayFracture A javascript file should not contain tags whatsoever.  And using the debugger in the browser (Chrome, IE, Firefox have one built in) can help you figure out where your code's not running correctly.

Comment: I'll make sure to correct that, thanks for the help. I'm new to web dev more used to algorithmic coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you want the ASP buttons doing post backs to the codebehind. You can see here https://jsfiddle.net/ax67cpjt/ that I just added your script and a button with the id `paymentButton` and it works fine.

Comment: That works thanks alot, but it is still flashing and then immediately exiting, it is executing the js script but it just flashes for a second.

Comment: What does your HTML look like now? Did you put the id on one of the ASP buttons?

Comment: I will update it above, and yes I did add                    <button id="paymentButton">
                    Click
                </button>
It just flashes

Comment: Add `type="button"` to the `<button>` element. `<button id="paymentButton" type="button">Click</button>`

Comment: WOW thanks alot Stephen, that solved it. I'm new to web dev, you were patient and helpful thanks again. Is there a reason why adding type fixed that?

Comment: Happy to help. The reason it was doing that is because the button is in the form element and so the default behavior is to submit.

Comment: Is there a way to this in codeback using C#, or would not be recommended as I would like to add multiple CC processors.

Comment: It looks like you could use their direct-api to do it https://github.com/SagePayments/Direct-API/tree/master/csharp but I don't know if you want to be in the business of handling customer credit card information, even if it is just posting the info back to the server.

Comment: ahh I see thanks for the clarification and links, Im just familiarizing myself with asp.net